# Vue.JS and VueX - problem with bind css class after commit in created function - using SSR

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i've just setup new vuex variable with mutation. I change variable on "created" vue.js function in component and it's worked. I've got value "true" of this variable but when i try to bind class in some parent component it does not work.

Parent component:

`<div class="subsections" :class="{'portfolio-page': this.$store.state.portfolioPages}">`

In mounted function console.log show "true" value.

SSR - **INITIAL_STATE** in source code display value true for this.

When i commit value of variable at mounted function in the same subsection - it's added class, but SSR got false value of this variable...

Answer (score 1):

Try with computed property with the getters like below

```
<div class="subsections" :class="{'portfolio-page': portfolioPages}">

<script>
new Vue({
   el : '#app',
   data:{
      ...
   },
   methods:{
      ...
   },
   computed:{
      portfolioPages(){
         return this.$store.getters.portfolioPages
      }
   }
})

<script>
```

And update your code in vuex also (store.js)

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
     state: {
        portfolio: 'lorem ipsum'
     },
     getters: {
        portfolioPages: state => {
           return state.portfolio
        }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will doesn't work. The main app.vue was rendering and if we want this variable we need to rerender whole component with all subcomponent, that's cannot be done...